# Overstayed visa J1, now coming back for vacations (2 weeks)

Tags: visa-refusals, esta, overstaying, j1-visas, french-citizens

I am a French national and I have done 2 consecutive J1 stays (1 year each). The first one was fine, and during the 2nd one I overstayed for about 1 month.

Now, 2 years later, I want to go back to the US as a tourist for 2 weeks. I've applied for an ESTA and it was approved (this is the first time I will use an ESTA to go to the US).

Will I be automatically denied entry at the border or will I be able to do my 2-week vacation? (I will attend a friend's wedding).

**Response to comments**

- Yes, I overstayed (1 month after the grace period).
- My online record (if you are talking about https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov) shows correctly the dates but does not indicate anywhere on the website that I have overstayed (no 'OVERSTAY' button or anything).

Comment: Does your online record say you overstayed?

Comment: Did you actually overstay or just make use of the J1 grace period?

Comment: You have a grace period of 30 days to depart the United States after your J1 visa has ended. Did you leave within that or 1 month after that?

Comment: @maxmax please contact a mod to merge your 2 accounts.

Comment: @Newton I don't think mods can do this any more, the OP needs to contact site services via the "contact" link at the bottom of each page.  Account merging is specifically listed as a contact reason there.

Comment: Ok I merged the accounts, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Were you asked a question on your ESTA application about whether you overstayed?

Comment: @user102008 The exact wording of the question appears to be “Have you ever stayed in the United States longer than the admission period granted to you by the U.S. government?”  Maxmax: did you answer *yes* to this question when you applied for your ESTA?

Comment: @phoog, I answered 'No' since when I answered I forgot about my overstay, and then just realized it 2days after - since I haven't been notified in any way that I have overstayed (on i94 website, or any other means)

Answer (score 3):

> Will I be automatically denied the entry at the border

Yes immediately, that is if they catch it. Now if they don't catch it and allow you to enter a zealous immigration officer one day will say you committed [fraud/misrepresentation](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume8-PartJ.html) at the time of entry because you knowingly entered with an automatically void ESTA  and that comes with a [lifetime bar to entry](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume8-PartJ-Chapter2.html).

> The person will be barred from admission for the rest of his or her
>   life unless the person qualifies for and is granted a waiver.

Even if the issue of fraud/misrepresentation is overlooked, you would be viewed to have accrued [unlawful presence](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/AFM/HTML/AFM/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-17138/0-0-0-18383.html) from the day you entered because you were [deportable as at the time of entry](http://myattorneyusa.com/section-237-deportability-statutes-inadmissible-at-time-of-entry-or-of-adjustment-of-status-or#INADMISSIBLE-AT-THE-TIME).

Heck you can actually be imprisoned (not just deported/refused entry) for attempted [illegal entry](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1325).

Basically just don't do it, apply for a visitor visa and be truthful.

[CBP Q/A](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1097/~/previously-denied-a-visa-or-immigration-benefit)

> How would my eligibility for a travel authorization via ESTA be
>   affected if I was previously denied a visa, previously denied an
>   immigration benefit, or previously committed an immigration-related
>   violation? If you were previously denied a visa, or previously refused
>   entry to the United States, or previously removed from the U.S., your
>   ESTA application **will most likely be denied**.

Comment: What do you mean by "if they catch it" ? Isn't this automatic (through internal programs etc...)

Comment: "Yes immediately" On what basis?

Comment: "an automatically void ESTA" On what basis do you say it is "automatically void"?

Comment: "you would be viewed to have accrued unlawful presence from the day you entered because you were deportable as at the time of entry." This is wrong. People do not accrue "unlawful presence" for being deportable. Also, I don't see any basis to say that he is deportable.

Comment: @maxmax It is not automatic because their systems sometimes don't catch these things, sometimes the immigration officer may miss it, etc. Errors happen a lot.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus: You made statements that certain things are "automatic" (automatically denied entry; ESTA automatically void), which means that you are claiming it to be a matter of law, not something up to discretion. Also, one cannot have "knowingly entered with a void ESTA" if it is not void according to law. And "unlawful presence" is a matter of law, not discretion. So in all of these cases, your claim needs to be backed by law.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus: "most likely" doesn't mean definitely, and doesn't mean if he gets it it is fraudlent

Comment: @MusoniusRufus I've read that even if I apply for a B2 and I get it, I'm not even 100% sure that I won't be denied at the border, so what's the point of applying for a visa? Also it says that I might be perma-ban from VWP and not all visas?

Comment: @maxmax If you don't want to apply for a visa don't. Show up at the airport and take your chances of getting refused entry, detained, and put on the next flight home. That's your prerogative, perhaps for you that is a pleasant experience and better applying for a visa where your worst case scenario is a denial and you get to walk home without the humiliation of detention, and deportation.