# If I get denied at the border (US) and I travel with my gf, are we both returned?

Tags: usa, esta, french-citizens

I will soon go to the US and might get denied (so then returned), but I am travelling with my GF and she has no reason to get denied but we are on the same ESTA and I bought the tickets for both of us.

What would be the procedure if I get denied? Will we both get returned?

Comment: Is your girlfriend a minor?

Comment: What does "on the same ESTA" mean? An ESTA applies to one person only.

Comment: @maxmax What makes you think you may be denied entry?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus No she is not a minor

Comment: @Traveller this doesn't matter in this question but you can check https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121089/overstayed-visa-j1-now-coming-back-for-vacations-2-weeks for more info

Comment: @GregHewgill, as 'same ESTA' it's that we paid together on the 'Group application' and not 'Individual application'

Comment: @DJClayworth How so?

Comment: @maxmax Even if you are allowed entry this visit, your overstay is going to hang over you every time you want to return to the US. Why not apply for a visa and remove the uncertainty?

Comment: @Traveller from what I understand, this will 'hang over' forever, if I get a visa or no, so I don't see a point of getting a visa in this case, it's not like I will be able to say 'I never overstayed' in case of a visa.

Comment: @maxmax True, but at least you’ll know beforehand, which would a) remove the stress of this trip if the application were approved; or b) save you the cost of a forced return and mean you don’t have a denial of entry record on your travel history to add to your already troublesome overstay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you are denied entry does not mean your girlfriend is, unless they believe she has aided you in making a fraudulent application. This is true no matter what kind of ESTA application you have.

She will not be 'returned' anywhere just because you are. If she wants to return with you she is going to have to pay for the appropriate tickets.